# Why does ffmpeg cut/trim off the end of my video when the bitrate is higher than normal?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to transcode some larger videos (10GB+) with higher bitrates (20Mbps), and I noticed that some (I can't find any pattern yet) will trim of a portion at the end (between 1 and 5 percent). It works spectacularly when the files are smaller or have a lower bitrate.

I'm quite new to ffmpeg, so I'm not sure where to start to diagnose the issue here.

Comment: Share full command and log. Add -report to have ffmpeg record these in a file for you.